# Google Play Services Connection Error

Tags: android, google-play

How would you handle displaying a connection error message to the user when we can't connect via Google Play and is missing?

This has to be Froyo compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display an alert when you got message from Google Play as `Connection Error` as below:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setMessage("Found some unknown Error. Please try again after some time.")
       .setCancelable(true)
       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });
      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
      alert.show();
```